# Scale down UIImage but returns larger memory size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want to scale down `UIImage` and use following method.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image convertToSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return destImage;
}
```

It returns correct dimensions but having larger image size(memory) than original image. How to optimize the method?

Comment: Make sure you use the same scale. Also the image will be represented differently.

Comment: When you say "larger than original one" do you mean larger than the `.png` file (or whatever it is)?

Answer (score -1):

You can compress your image so its size will decrese

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
```